# avoid redirecting all folder as hostname in wamp

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have created two one virtual host and other are normal folder.my virtual host name is testVirtualHost.Along with this I have other folder as'trial','learn'.
other folder are also redirect as http:/learn instead of localhost/learn and vice versa.I have given below my virtual host code in 'httpd-vhosts.conf'.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\testVirtualHost"
    ServerName testVirtualHost
    ServerAlias testVirtualHost
</VirtualHost>
```